# How to get the type of a non-initialized variable in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typechecking, typescript-compiler-api

I've been trying to understand how to get the TypeScript type of a variable that is not initialized when declared.
Basically what I want is to programmatically, possibly using the TypeScript API, get the inferred type of a variable that's been declared without a type and without an initializer.
I'll explain better:
Let's suppose I have this code:

```
let a = 'hi';
```

Then I would get a suggestion to infer type of the variable and I would get as a type `'string'`.
I can get this inferred type with:
 `const type = program.getTypeChecker().typeToString(program.getTypeChecker().getTypeAtLocation(node));`. Where `program` comes from TS `languageServices.getProgram();` and `node` in this case would be of kind `SyntaxKind.VariableDeclaration`.
However this code would not work correctly with something like:

```
let a;
a = 'hi';
```

In this case I would get `'any'` even though from the editor I still can get the correct suggestion of `'string'`. The same applies for a scenario like

```
let a;
a = 'hi';
a = 5;
a = true;
```

Where I would get `'any'` even though the correct inferred type would be `'string | number | boolean'`.
I think I understood that it's normal my line of code shouldn't work in the last two scenarios because there's no type at the variable declaration node.
However I've not been able to find any other way to get the correct inferred type for variable declarations without an initializer.
Here the logs of the ts node (of the last example):
[image: node log]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can declare a variable with type ```let a: string;```. For multiple types you can do ```let a: string | number | boolean ```

Comment: @AbhinKrishnaKA thank you, but this is not what I want. What I want is to programmatically, possibly using the TypeScript API, get the inferred type of a variable that's been declared without a type and without an initializer.